# Failed to look up JNDI DataSource

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This problem may seems redundant but I can't find a suitable solution for my specific problem.

So, I have been using basic JDBC template to make connection to the DB tables in my spring boot application. I have few more features to add and I wanted to follow JPA route. I added `spring.datasource.jndi-name` and `spring.jpa.database-platform` to the application.properties file correctly(same as once that are working in my other applications).
Although I'm able to run the current application(with both JPA and JDBC connection) locally, I'm getting following error while building it on weblogic remote server.

`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'jdbc.myDataSource'; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial`

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: What version of spring and what are your dependencies (eg which spring/spring-boot jars are you using)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I using spring boot version 2.4.5.